# What can cause an .aspx page to ignore its corresponding .cs file?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

For a school project, I'm forced to use Visual Studio and ASP to implement an interactive course catalogue website. Due to time constraints, we're putting together a table-based design where one column implements a MultiView and the other shows a GridView.

The first MultiView implements a ListView along with a text search bar.  When a user makes a selection in the ListView, the goal is to fire off the ListBox1_SelectionIndexChanged event handler, whose job is to execute a query based on the SelectedIndex.

All fine and dandy... or at least it seemed.

In practice, however, the entire .cs file is getting skipped over for some reason.  I found this out when setting several breakpoints for debugging only to find out that setting breakpoints on global array declarations as well as the Page_Load methods were ignored when running the debugger.

I thought it could be something with the header of the aspx file.  However, given that the aspx file is named `Default.aspx` and the CodeBehind field has `Default.aspx.cs` listed.

So, what the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `<%@Page %>` directive at the top of `Default.aspx` specifies the following:

```
Inherits="_Default" AutoEventWireup="true"
```

Note that the `Inherits` attribute refers to the partial class name in `Default.aspx.cs`, which will probably be called `_Default`.

Comment: If, however, the partial class name in Default.aspx.cs is not `Default`, you may have to change it.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm getting at when I say that attribute refers to the name of the *partial class* defined in `Default.aspx.cs`

Comment: Just clarifying, you got my +1

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it was already specified as that and the problem continues.  This is probably due to the fact we're adapting an existing project's code to this project with little to no idea what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Make sure `AutoEventWireup="true"` is also set. If it's not, methods like `Page_Load` won't get called.

Answer (score 0):

if above solution didnt help you, just try to add a new page to the folder where this page is.  Then look for any differences at the very top of .aspx pages and .cs pages.